# Does it cause problems to have a table associated with multiple content types?

Tags: mysql, database-design, content-management-system

I have multiple content types, but they all share some similarities.  I'm wondering when it is a problem to use the same table for a different content type?  Is it ever a problem?  If so, why?

Here's an example: I have five kinds of content, and they all have a title.  So, can't I just use a 'title' table for all five content types?

Extending that example: a title is technically a name.  People and places have names.  Would it be bad to put all of my content titles, people names, and place names in a "name" table?  Why separate into place_name, person_name, content_title?

I have different kinds of content.  In the database, they seem very similar, but the application uses the content in different ways, producing different outputs.  Do I need a new table for each content type because it has a different result with different kinds of dependencies, or should I just allow null values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While normalization is a very good practice to avoid redundency and ensure consistency, it can be bad for performance sometimes. For example for a `person` table where you have columns like `name`, `adress`, `dob` its not very good performance wise to have a `picture` in the same table. A picture can be about 1MB easily while the remaining columns may not take any more than 1K. Imagine how many blokcs of data needed to be read even if you only want to list the name and address of people living in a certain city - if you are keeping everything in the same table.

If there is a variation in size of the contents and you might have to retrieve only certain types of contents in the same query, the performance gain from storing them in separate tables will outweight the normalization easily.

Comment: That's interesting, and I hadn't thought about it, Raihan.  The database I'm working on is one that you might call "hyper normalized", already, though.  For example, I don't have a person table with a name, address, and dob.  I have a person id table, a name table, an address table, and a dob table.

Comment: "Normalization is the process of simplifying the design of a database so that it achieves the optimum structure". Normalization genrally means splliting relations in tables. It also means not to over split. `Person{pid, name, address, pictuire}` would be a normalized structure for the `Person` relation (unless you want to further decompose `address`). Splitting it into `Person{pid, name, address}` and `PersonPicture{pid, pictuire}` is not a normalized structure but might be better from performance perspective. Thats what I meant to say in my post.

Comment: @wolfpack, that isn;t hypernormalized, it's just plain bad design. How many people have more than one date of birth? There is no reason to pullthat out from the person table. Addresses are a 1-many relationship and should be pulled out but DOB!

Comment: @HLGEM On a social networking site, I'd say about 1/50 people have multiple DOB's.  I can see how it would be reasonable to keep in the person table, though. :)  Anyway, with that level of normalization in mind, can you see why I'm thinking about combining the name tables?

Comment: But anyway, when having more and more tables, are we talking about hair-thin/millisecond differences?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do that.

If there are multiple columns that are the same among multiple tables, you should indeed normalize these to 1 table.

And example of that would be several types of users, which all require different columns, but all share some characteristics (e.g. name, address, phone number, email address)
These could be normalized to 1 table, which is then referenced to by all other tables through a foreign key. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization )

Your example only shows 1 common column, which is not worth normalizing. It would even reduce performance trying to fetch your data, because you'll need to join 2 tables to get all data; 1 of which (the one with the titles) contains a lot of data you won't need all the data from, thus straining the server more.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the info you're giving seems to conflict with itself, to me.  If I were normalizing tables, I'd be creating new tables, right?  So, I'm not sure if I know what you mean.

Comment: Yes, during the normalization, you would create a new table for multiple common columns among multiple tables. Given there's only 1 common column here (name/title), the normalization is useless and would only stress the server more, not giving you any normalization benefit.

Comment: The tables are only 3-column tables: title id, title content, title status.  They're basically exactly the same and contain nothing additionally.

Comment: You wouldn't have "title id" in the not-normalized version. However, if there are 2 common columns in all tables already (title content, title status), it then would be perfectly sane to normalize them :p - thought there was only 1 common column 'title'

Comment: Yes, it's been an interesting process designing this database.  I'll give it some more thought.  You've definitely given me some ideas.  I still worry that there may be some issue, like it may be confusing, or having a `content type` identifier--an added column--might cause problems.  I guess it's one low-cost column at the expense of many tables spread out all over the nasty place, though.

Answer (score 0):

To typify data in this way, it's best to use a table (i.e., `name`), and a sub-table (i.e., `name_type`), and then use a FK constraint.  Use an `FK constraint` because the `InnoDB` does not support column constraints, and the `MyISAM` engine is not suited for this (it is much less robust and feature rich, and it should really only be used for performance).

This kind of normailization is fine, but it should be done with a free-format column type, like `VARCHAR(40)`, rather than with `ENUM`.  Use triggers to restrict the input so that it matches the types you want to support.